# what are the formats supported in Pygame for playing sound?

Tags: python, pygame

Which sound formats are supported in these modules:

```
pygame.mixer.sound
```

or:

```
pygame.mixer.music
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [pygame documentation:](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html)

> The Sound can be loaded from an OGG audio file or from an uncompressed WAV.

As for `Music`, it seems to support several different including MP3 (limited), OGG, XM & MOD. See [Documentation for music](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html) (and the comments on that page).

Answer (score 2):

You may want to have a look here : http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Sound

> The Sound can be loaded from an OGG audio file or from an uncompressed WAV